# Access rails engine routes directly from URL path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rails-engines

I am trying to access

```
POST http://localhost:3000/login
```

MyEngine routes

```
devise_for :accounts, { class_name: 'MyEngine::Account', skip: [:sessions, :registration, :password] }
    as :account do
     post 'login', to: 'sessions#create'
    end
```

My Application Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount MyEngine::Engine => '/engine', as: 'engine'
end
```

Commented isolation Space

```
module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    #isolate_namespace MyEngine
  end
end
```

Error after hitting POST http://localhost:3000/login

```
#<ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [POST] \"/login\">
```

How to access login method of Engine from URL path directly?

Comment: Can you post your whole `routes.rb` file ?

Comment: is url like this `/engine/login` ? as per your main **route.rb** your url suppose to be this

Comment: Yes, /engine/login it went inside sessions controller. But now I am getting Started POST "/abc_services_core/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-23 15:22:37 +0530

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant SessionsController):

Comment: sessions controller is like this inside engine-class MyEngine::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController end

Answer (score 1):

The error **uninitialized constant SessionsController** happening because rails not able to locate your sessions controller so if you are overriding default devise specify custom controller path inside routes.

> Engine routes

```
devise_for :accounts, { class_name: 'MyEngine::Account', skip: [:sessions, :registration, :password], controllers: { sessions: "my_engine/sessions"} } as :account do
 post 'login', to: 'sessions#create'
end
```

`controllers: { sessions: "my_engine/sessions"}` here you can see i have specify the sessions path.

> config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # your main routes 
  mount MyEngine::Engine => '/engine', as: 'engine'
end
```

> your sessions controller will be as follows:

```
  MyEngine::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  end
```

Comment: Thank you Vishal, my problem is solved by adding engine name space in route.  

post 'login', to: 'my_engine/sessions#create', as: 'login'